# Is it possible to attach an onclicklistener to a chooser intent?

Tags: android, android-intent

Is it possible to attach an onclicklistener to a custom chooser or chooser intent?

I want to know if a user actually clicks on one of the options presented them during a send intent.

Comment: Were you able to solve this? I currently have a situation where I need to know which item was selected from the chooser intent.

Comment: Unfortunately no, I was not.  I no longer work for the company I did this app for, and I don't know if they ever solved it.  Sorry